# Partial View Action does'nt populate model data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a partial view which contains some data from the Model to be displayed. i created an Action of this Partial View in which I return the Model ,I want t display Partial view in each View of my MVC project. but the Problem is that when i return the Model in each View Method Action then it returns the Model and display data but when i am not using to return the Model in each view and want to return the Model only in the Partial view Action then data Model data is not Populating on Partial view .

I want to Return the Model only in the Partial view Action .My code is

```
public PartialViewResult _FlyMenu()
{
    Category cat = new Category();
    var category1 =cat.CategoryName;

    return PartialView(category1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't anything passed to the partial view action, so there isn't anything that action can pass to the partial view itself.

There should be an argument for the model in the redirect call, and a parameter in the action arguments to receive it.

Assuming your model is of type Category I think you'd need something like this:

```
public PartialViewResult _FlyResult(Category c)
{
    // method body here
}
```